# SQL: using max(count(() instead of LIMIT 1

Tags: count, group-by, subquery, max, sql-order-by

currentlly I am very disappointed. I am try since days to use instead of order by count DESC and LIMIT 1 just something max(count()). I know this is not exactlly possible. There must be something like to. Because imagine there two of the same count.

```
SELECT display_name, location 
FROM users
WHERE id = (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM badges
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY count(id)  DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

So it s probably pretty easy but I don't get how to handle it. Would be really amazed if someone will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
SELECT display_name, location 
FROM users
WHERE id = (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM badges
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(user_id) = 1
)
```

The inner query would select all user that only have one badge

Not sure what you wanted to achieve with the DESC, but you could use it in the outer query to ORDER the results on display_name or location or add the id to the select and select on that.

```
SELECT id, display_name, location 
FROM users
WHERE id = (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM badges
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(user_id) = 1
) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```